# Does not get the time difference correct in PHP

Tags: php

```
$time1 = "01:00";
$time2 = "04:55";
list($hours1, $minutes1) = explode(':', $time1);
$startTimestamp = mktime($hours1, $minutes1);

list($hours2, $minutes2) = explode(':', $time2);
$endTimestamp = mktime($hours2, $minutes2);

$seconds = $endTimestamp - $startTimestamp;
$minutes = ($seconds / 60) % 60;
$hours = round($seconds / (60 * 60));

echo $hours.':'.$minutes;
exit;
```

Outputs 4:55, should be 3:55 ?

Whats wrong here? If it is 01:00 and 02:00, it works fine, but not with the above?

Comment: I don't know, but `DateTime` and `DateInterval` class will solve you headaches.

Comment: @moonwave99 No, tried that, the hours resets then after 24 hours, which will not be right for my program

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `floor` instead of `round`...

Answer (score 0):

Or just cast to integer.

```
$hours = (int) ($seconds / (60 * 60));
```

Answer (score 0):

Too many calculations when PHP can do it for you with also reducing possibility of error

```
$time1 = Datetime::createFromFormat("h:i", "01:00");
$time2 = Datetime::createFromFormat("h:i", "04:55");

$diff = $time1->diff($time2);
var_dump($diff->format("%h %i"));
```

Output

```
string '3:55' (length=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also save yourself some time by using `strtotime`:

```
$time1 = strtotime("01:00");
$time2 = strtotime("04:55");

$seconds = $time2-$time1;
$minutes = ($seconds / 60) % 60;
$hours = floor($seconds / (60 * 60));

echo $hours.':'.$minutes;
```

As mentioned, using `floor` will produce the result you need:

**Result**

```
3:55
```